# How to print own script name in mawk?

Tags: awk, scripting, mawk

In bash `$0` contains the name of the script, but in awk if I make a script named myscript.awk with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{ print ARGV[0] }
```

and run it, it will only print "awk". Besides, ARGV[i] with i>0 is used only for script arguments in command line.
So, how to make it print the name of the script, in this case "myscript.awk"?

Comment: I've changed the title from awk to mawk because all the solutions require gawk and don't work with general awk, and in particular with mawk which is widely used (e.g. default on Ubuntu)

Comment: What makes you think `mawk` is default on Ubuntu? On my 15.04 VM, the default `awk` is `gawk`. While mawk is installed it is not the default.

Comment: What you have posted is a shell script, not an awk script, so it shoud be named "myscript.sh" or similar, not "myscript.awk". That fact that you are calling awk inside that shell script is completely irrelevant - you could replace awk with perl or a bunch of shell commands and the script would have the same functionality and it'd still be a shell script.

Comment: It's an awk script if you call it by `awk -f myscript.awk`. However, this is unrelated to the problem in question.

Comment: @EdMorton It's an `awk` script because it begins with `#!/usr/bin/awk -f`. Shell scripts begin with `#!/bin/sh` (or something similar).

Comment: I've been talking to various shell experts and trying to get a definitive answer on whether that's a shell or awk script and surprisingly according to POSIX the interpretation of files that begin with #! is undefined and has no specific type name. While some people refer to it as a "hash bang interpreter script" rather than a shell or awk script, the consensus seems to be that it should be considered an awk script even though the kernel (not shell) interprets the first line because awk still has to be able to parse that first line too (as a comment) and you can execute it using `awk -f file`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With GNU awk 4.1.3 in bash on cygwin:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { print "Executing:", ENVIRON["_"] }

$ ./tst.sh
Executing: ./tst.sh
```

I don't know how portable that is. As always, though, I wouldn't execute an awk script using a shebang in a shell script as it just robs you of possible functionality. Keep it simple and just do this instead:

```
$ cat tst2.sh
awk -v cmd="$0" '
BEGIN { print "Executing:", cmd }
' "$@"

$ ./tst2.sh
Executing: ./tst2.sh
```

That last will work with any modern awk in any shell on any platform.

Comment: Note that the first one only work in bash, zsh or ksh. The later is about shell script, not awk script.

Comment: The OP simply wants to print the name of a shell script which he has very unfortunately named `myscript.awk`.

Comment: Let @cipper clarify.

Comment: Thank you! `ENVIRON["_"]` works perfectly, and it doesn't call any external program. The second option `awk -v ...` depends on how one runs the script; I don't want this.

Comment: @cipper: Don't rely on it, as I said in my comment above, it only work with bash, zsh, or ksh variants.

Comment: Calling your script `tst.sh` is misleading. It's an `awk` script, not a shell script. `BEGIN` is not a valid shell command.

Comment: `ENVIRON` is very portable. It is a [special variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_03) defined in the POSIX standard itself.

Comment: Right but the portability question isn't "is ENVIRON[] portable" it's "does `ENVIRON["_"]` produce the calling shell script path when printed from every awk called via a shebang from every shell"? I would never call an awk script from a shebang to I personally don't care about the answer but just thought I'd mention it.... Oh I see in the comments above that @cuonglm answered that it's only supported in some shells.

Comment: Good point, @Ed.  Verified as failing in dash (which returns the _previous_ command (or else the shell itself) rather than the current one). ksh93 interestingly prefixes the PID in asterisks, e.g. `*12345*/tmp/test.awk`.  `ARGV[0]` is reliably always `awk` in dash, bash, zsh, and ksh93.

Comment: instead of `-v cmd="$0"`, you could do a more complex one to : 1) take into account non-gnu environnements (but I still assume you use bash... ymmv), 2) find if possible the name of a sourced script, and whether the scirpt is invoked with a full path, from $PATH, etc : with : `truename=${BASH_SOURCE[0]:-$0}; name="$( basename "$truename" )"; dir="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$truename" )" && pwd)"; awk -v cmd="${dir}/${name}" '....' "$@"`

Answer (score 7):

I don't know any direct way of getting the command name from within awk. You can however find it through a sub-shell.

#### gawk

With GNU awk and the `ps` command you can use the process ID from `PROCINFO["PID"]` to retrieve the command name as a workaround. For example:

*cmdname.awk*

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
  ("ps -p " PROCINFO["pid"] " -o comm=") | getline CMDNAME
  print CMDNAME
}
```

#### mawk and nawk

You can use the same approach, but derive `awk`'s PID from the `$PPID` special shell variable (PID of the parent):

*cmdname.awk*

```
#!/usr/bin/mawk -f

BEGIN { 
  ("ps -p $PPID -o comm=") | getline CMDNAME
  print CMDNAME
}
```

#### Testing

Run the script like this:

```
./cmdname.awk
```

Output in both cases:

```
cmdname.awk
```

Comment: I got an error:

    /bin/sh: 1: -o: not found

Comment: @cipper: This only works with GNU awk, I added the missing shebang line.

Comment: From [gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fPipe):

_According to POSIX, ‘expression | getline’ is ambiguous if expression 
contains unparenthesized operators other than ‘$’—for example, ‘"echo " "date" | getline’ is ambiguous because the concatenation operator is not parenthesized. You should write it as ‘("echo " "date") | getline’ if you want your program to be portable to all awk implementations._

Comment: but we cannot use parentheses in your method because PROCINFO would be interpreted as bash command as well...

Comment: @cipper: The `PROCINFO` hash is GNU awk specific, so this only works with GNU awk.

Comment: On default ubuntu it does not work. It would be nice to find a portable solution.

Comment: @cipper:  then use the answer by _cuonglm_.

Comment: If it needs `gawk` it is a `gawk` solution instead of an `awk` solution. I think @cipper should add his wish "a portable solution" to the question.

Comment: @Thor: the answer by cuonglm is not a solution since it requires to feed manually the script with its name. It's like calling `awk -vNAME="myscript.awk" ./myscript.awk` and then print NAME inside the script. Not a solution.

Comment: @cipper: You can get the process id through a sub-shell in mawk. See the edit.

Comment: I just found out you were already using the PROCINFO approach, which I didn't see when I posted my answer. I will keep mine since I use `system()`, but of course +1 yours!

Comment: @fedorqui: no worries, you also quoted the relevant manual bits and showed an alternative use of `ps`.

Comment: Why not simply `"ps -p $PPID -o comm=" | getline`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Not sure why I used two sub-shells. I have updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Note that there's nothing Linux specific in there. The only non-POSIX feature is gawk's `PROCINFO["pid"]` here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: The wording is better now thanks.  You are right as well about it not being Linux specific, the solution only requires a way to get at the process id and associated command name.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is possible as per `gawk` [documentation](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_15.html):

> Finally, the value of `ARGV[0]` (see section 7.5 Built-in Variables) varies depending upon your operating system. Some systems put `awk` there, some put the full pathname of awk (such as `/bin/awk`), and some put the name of your script ('advice'). Don't rely on the value of `ARGV[0]` to provide your script name.

On `linux` you can try using a kind of a dirty hack and as pointed in comments by [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) it is possible if implementation of `awk` supports NUL bytes:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { getline t < "/proc/self/cmdline"; split(t, a, "\0"); print a[3]; }
```

Comment: your script as is seems not working. It just prints "k" if called with "awk -f script.awk", and it prints "s" if called by "./script.awk"

Comment: @cipper: Here it works with `gawk` and fails (like your description) with `mawk`. Interesting!

Comment: It works for me in linux, `awk` - 4.0.2. In freebsd with `/proc/curpoc/cmdline`, and `awk` result is like yours but works with `gawk`.

Comment: On default ubuntu it does not work. It would be nice to find a portable solution.

Comment: @cipper, consider cuonglm answer.

Comment: @taliezin: the answer by cuonglm is not a solution since it requires to feed manually the script with its name. It's like calling `awk -vNAME="myscript.awk" ./myscript.awk` and then print NAME inside the script. Not a solution.

Comment: @cipper, I see, but I think there is no portable solution.

Comment: You need an implementation of `awk` that supports NUL bytes. So only gawk and recent versions of mawk.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I added this to the answer.

Comment: Use this instead: no need to parse null bytes: `BEGIN { getline < "/proc/self/comm"; print }`. You can also assign the value to a variable from `$0`.

Answer (score 5):

With POSIX `awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    print ENVIRON["AWKSCRIPT"]
}
```

Then:

```
AWKSCRIPT=test.awk ./test.awk
test.awk
```

Comment: You manually feed the name of the script in it, this is not a self-printing way

Comment: @cipper: Well, that's the easiest and portable way I can imagine.

Comment: It's like calling `awk -vNAME="myscript.awk" ./myscript.awk` and then print the variable `NAME` inside the script. Not a solution.

Comment: @cipper: That's the only way, if you mention `mawk`. And also using `ENVIRON` isn't the same as using `-vNAME="myscript.awk"`, since when `mawk` will expand escape sequence in `NAME`.

Answer (score 4):

## Using GNU awk

Checking the [GNU awk user's guide - 7.5.2 Built-in Variables That Convey Information](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html) I stumbled upon:

> PROCINFO #
>
> The elements of this array provide access to information about the
>   running awk program. The following elements (listed alphabetically)
>   are guaranteed to be available:
>
> **PROCINFO["pid"]**
>
> The process ID of the current process.

This means that you can know the PID of the program during runtime. Then, it is a matter of using `system()` to look for the process with this given PID:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN{ pid=PROCINFO["pid"]
       system("ps -ef | awk '$2==" pid " {print $NF}'")
}
```

I use `ps -ef`, which displays the PID on the 2nd column. Assuming the executiong is done through `awk -f <script>` and no other parameters, we can assume the last field of the line contains the information we want.

In case we had some parameters, we would have to parse the line differently -or, better, use some of the options of `ps` to print just the columns we are interested in.

#### Test

```
$ awk -f a.awk 
a.awk
$ cp a.awk hello.awk
$ awk -f hello.awk 
hello.awk
```

---

Note also that another chapter of the GNU awk user's guide tells us that ARGV is not the way to go:

> [1.1.4 Executable awk Programs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Executable-Scripts.html)
>
> Finally, the value of ARGV[0] (see Built-in Variables) varies
>   depending upon your operating system. Some systems put ‘awk’ there,
>   some put the full pathname of awk (such as /bin/awk), and some put the
>   name of your script (‘advice’). (d.c.) **Don’t rely on the value of
>   ARGV[0] to provide your script name.**

Comment: unfortunately PROCINFO is only a gawk feature, not general awk. For example it is not available in mawk (which is installed by default in ubuntu)

Comment: I know... Why did you tag the question with [gawk] then?

Comment: You're right. When I posted the question I wasn't aware about all these differences between mawk and gawk. The tag has changed to mawk now.

Comment: @cipper good : ) I was in fact testing with `mawk` and couldn't make it work, so that I installed `gawk` in my Ubuntu and it worked. So a workaround can be to use `gawk` : D

Comment: I know, but I prefer a portable solution since mawk is installed by default in all debian-based distros (basically half of the linux platforms, at least)

Comment: @terdon, `gawk` is not installed by default on Ubuntu (or at least some Ubuntu versions, where `mawk` is the default `awk` implementation). IIRC, I had to install it as well on Debian.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas well I'll be! You're quite right, I just tested this on an Ubuntu VM. I stand corrected, thanks.

Comment: @terdon, yes confirmed in a dpkg.log. mawk is also the default awk implementation on Debian (at least stretch) and gawk is not installed by default.